# Как правильно подключить скрипт внутри файла php темы wordpress?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Приветствую. Подскажите, как правильно и безопасно подключить скрипт внутри файла php темы wordpress?
`add_action()` ведь работает только для functions.php или я заблуждаюсь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавить скрипт в тему можно с помощью функции `wp_enqueue_script()`

Подробнее о данном методе можно почитать [тут](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BC/wp_enqueue_script).

Comment: я же не спрашиваю как добавить скрипт в файл functions.php. прочитайте плиз вопрос и комменты внимательно

Comment: @Вася вы сами определитесь чего вы хотите, Alexandr ответил на ваш вопрос

Answer (score 2):

Можно просто закинуть js-ник в нужную тебе папку с сайтом, а коннект js-ника прописать к примеру в header.php или template.php вида

```
<script type="text/javascript">твой скрипт</script>
```